# Setting rules for max() with strings

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Each record in my table has a random selection of these strings, so it looks like

```
record   fruit
A        pear
A        apple_guava
A        pear_guava
A        mango_guava
B        mango
C        apple_guava
C        pear_guava
```

I want to get the highest value of "fruit" for each record, except I want it to be sorted lower if it contains the string guava. This is the output that I'd like and I'm using Snowflake SQL

output:

```
record   fruit
A        pear
B        mango
C        apple_guava
```

Currently, I'm trying to do this by assigning every possible value of fruit a number with a case when statemnet, using max on that list and the converting the result back into a string. That won't work in my case because the names of the fruit will change, so I don't want a hard coded list

this is what I've tried

```
select
   record,
   left(max(case when fruit ilike '%guava%' then z || fruit else fruit end), 1) as fruit
from table
group by 1
```

Comment: Please explain what "highest value" means?  What is the value?  I fixed the database tag based on what you say in the question.  Postgres <> Snowflake.

Comment: Why did you tag the database as "PostgreSQL" but you say you are using Snowflake? Which one is it?

Comment: It's snowflake, not postgres. Highest value is descending alphabetical order with the 'guava' values at the bottom, also in descending alphabetical order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desired results with Snowflake (as tagged):

- `array_agg()` can be ordered
- for the order we can sort first by `guava` existing, and then by fruit.
- `[0]` obtains the first element of `array_agg()`.

```sql
with data as (
    select split(value, '        ')[0]::string record, split(value, '        ')[1]::string fruit
    from table(split_to_table(
'A        pear
A        apple_guava
A        pear_guava
A        mango_guava
B        mango
C        apple_guava
C        pear_guava'
    , '\n'))
)           

select record
  , (array_agg(distinct fruit) 
     within group (
         order by contains(fruit, 'guava'), fruit
     ))[0]::string max_fruit
from data
group by record
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The original question was tagged Postgres, so this is a Postgres solution.

Assuming you have some ordering -- let's use alphabetical for this example -- then you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (record) r.*
from t
order by record,
         (fruit not like '%guava%') desc,  -- non-guava first
         fruit desc;
```

With Snowflake (or any other database), you can use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by record.
                                order by (fruit not like '%guava%') desc, fruit desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=4fa90189580f6ba44bde68fe5cadeaec) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: @Cauder . . . Presumably you mean `case` **expression**.  And you can  include such an expression in `ORDER BY`.

Comment: @Cauder . . . There is no `max()` function in this answer.

Comment: Might be best if you post what you've already tried @Cauder